# Cannot resolve symbol List<LatLng> google maps API

Tags: android, list, gradle, geolocation, google-api

I am trying to create an application which would calculate everything I need for my route, using google API.

I was following very nice guides here on StackOverflow, but now I encountered problem that nobody seemed to have.

```
List<LatLng> cannot be resolved as symbol
```

**My Snippet:**

```
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    public void drawPath(String result) {

        try {
            //Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

            for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
                LatLng src = list.get(z);
                LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
                Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                        .width(2)
                        .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
```

This is the part of the code where I recieve an error.

**My Imports:**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

**My Gradle File:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appID"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Can someone please help? I am assuming that the problem is with Google API, because I cannot include it to my project.

I appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: well you didnt import any of the google maps stuff in your class

Comment: I forgot to copy it here, I have imported following from Google API:
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

Comment: @tyczj I have now only problem with `mMap`, it says it cannot resolve they symbol. I guess another importis missing, but I do not know which ..